# EXT js 4.1.1 Tree panel expand collapse icon is not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, panel

Here i'm using Ext js 4.1, When i click on the collapse icon it is not changing to expand state.
This happens only in IE. Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4ja

Comment: What error do you find in console?

Comment: HI A1rPun , Please change framework dropdown to classic 4.1.